# Combined two dataframe based on index, replacing matching values in other column

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have the following wide df1:

```
Area geotype  type    ...
1      a        2      ...
1      a        1      ... 
2      b        4      ...
4      b        8      ...
```

And the following two-column df2:

```
Area   geotype
1      London
4      Cambridge
```

And I want the following:

```
Area  geotype  type    ...
1     London     2      ...
1     London     1      ... 
2       b        4      ...
4     Cambridge  8      ...
```

So I need to match based on the non-unique Area column, and then only if there is a match, replace the set values in the geotype column.

Apologies if this is a duplicate, I did actually search hard for a solution to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `update` + `map`

```
df1.geotype.update(df1.Area.map(df2.set_index('Area').geotype))

   Area    geotype  type
0     1     London     2
1     1     London     1
2     2          b     4
3     4  Cambridge     8
```

Comment: @jezrael fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then fill `NaN` values by [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df1.geotype = df1.ID.map(df2.set_index('ID')['geotype']).combine_first(df1.geotype)
#df1.geotype = df1.ID.map(df2.set_index('ID')['geotype']).fillna(df1.geotype)
print (df1)
   ID    geotype type
0   1     London    2
1   2          a    1
2   3          b    4
3   4  Cambridge   8e
```

Another solution with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
df1.geotype = df1.geotype.mask(np.in1d(df1.ID, df2.ID),
                               df1.ID.map(df2.set_index('ID')['geotype']))
print (df1)
   ID    geotype type
0   1     London    2
1   2          a    1
2   3          b    4
3   4  Cambridge   8e
```

EDIT by comment:

Problem is not unique `ID` values in `df2` like:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 4], 'geotype': ['London', 'Paris', 'Cambridge']})
print (df2)
   ID    geotype
0   1     London
1   1      Paris
2   4  Cambridge
```

So function `map` cannot choose right value and raise error.

Solution is remove duplicates by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), by default keep first value:

```
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates('ID')
print (df2)
   ID    geotype
0   1     London
2   4  Cambridge
```

Or if need keep last value:

```
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates('ID', keep='last')
print (df2)
   ID    geotype
1   1      Paris
2   4  Cambridge
```

---

If cannot remove duplicates, there is another solution with outer [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), but there are duplicated rows where is duplicated `ID` in `df2`:

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID', how='outer', suffixes=('_',''))
df1.geotype = df1.geotype.combine_first(df1.geotype_)
df1 = df1.drop('geotype_', axis=1)
print (df1)
   ID type    geotype
0   1    2     London
1   1    2      Paris
2   2    1          a
3   3    4          b
4   4   8e  Cambridge
```

Comment: Sorry, I got 'Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects' as the ID column is really an area column, so there are multiple entries.

Comment: I see problem - You have for one `ID` in `df2` multiple values, so `map` is impossible - pandas does not know if need first value or first `ID`. You need unique values of `ID` in `df2`

Answer (score 2):

alternative solution:

```
In [78]: df1.loc[df1.ID.isin(df2.ID), 'geotype'] = df1.ID.map(df2.set_index('ID').geotype)

In [79]: df1
Out[79]:
   ID    geotype  type
0   1     London     2
1   2          a     1
2   3          b     4
3   4  Cambridge     8
```

**UPDATE:** answers **updated** question - if you have duplicates in the `Area` column in the `df2` DF:

```
In [152]: df1.loc[df1.Area.isin(df2.Area), 'geotype'] = df1.Area.map(df2.set_index('Area').geotype)
...
skipped
...
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

get rid of duplicates:

In [153]: df1.loc[df1.Area.isin(df2.Area), 'geotype'] = df1.Area.map(df2.drop_duplicates(subset='Area').set_index('Area').geotype)

In [154]: df1
Out[154]:
   Area    geotype  type
0     1     London     2
1     1     London     1
2     2          b     4
3     4  Cambridge     8
```

Comment: Sorry, I got 'Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects' as the ID column is really an area column, so there are multiple entries.

Comment: @ThirstforKnowledge, do you also have duplicates in the `df2` DF?

Comment: No just duplicates in df1 @MaxU